# Building condition to do filtering later

Tags: c#

The goal is to have some code to build filtering condition for `Where` call.

In FoxPro I'd use condition built as string (`"foo == 3 && bar > 5"`) and execute it later.

I am trying similar approach in C#  - create string and use it as condition in the code below but can't find way to do it:

```
string Condition = "";

...
if (xyz > 0)
    Condition = "scr.ZipCode = 12345";

if (xyz > 1)
    Condition = "scr.ZipCode = 23456";

if (xyz > 2)
    Condition = "scr.ZipCode = 34567";

...etc.
```

and then use it in the code:

```
var shippingShipCalculatorRecords = 
   _shippingShipCalculatorService.GetAllShippingShipCalculatorRecords()
            .Where(scr => (
                              (scr.CountryId == 0 && Condition)
                          )
            .OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList();
```

I've tried to convert it to bool but it didn't work neither. I use to work in FoxPro and could easily achieve it (&Condition).

Comment: You can't execute code from a string.  Instead, store the zip code in the string.

Comment: Looks like it actually not a duplicate (as Servy's answer got positive feedback from OP - voting to reopen).

Comment: @user3170203, I've edited question to be more about "building condition" (which seem to be your goal) rather than "parsing condition from string". Feel free to edit your post if my changes are not inline with your actual problem. Also if Servy's answer is what you need - accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than making your condition a string, have it be an `Expression<Func<YourEntityType, bool>>` so that you can still have compile time verification that your syntax is all valid:

```
Expression<Func<YourEntityType, bool>> Condition;

if (xyz > 0)
    Condition = scr => scr.ZipCode == 12345;
else if (xyz > 1)
    Condition = scr => scr.ZipCode == 23456;
else if (xyz > 2)
    Condition = scr => scr.SomeOtherField == "someStringValue";
else 
    Condition = scr => true; //or whatever makes sense as a default choice

var shippingShipCalculatorRecords = 
    _shippingShipCalculatorService.GetAllShippingShipCalculatorRecords()
            .Where(scr => scr.CountryId == 0)
            .Where(Condition)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList();
```

Comment: +1. This is much safe approach than parsing string (as it is completely strongly typed).

Comment: This seems to be the solution. Servy was reading my mind because I used ZipCode only as a sample for table field, but Condition could be based on any other field (SomeOtherField).

Comment: In lines with "Condition = scr => scr.ZipCode == " I am getting error that string scr. doesn't contain definition for "ZipCode"?

Comment: @user3170203 Then either the type you defined in the definition of `Condition` isn't the proper type, or your type doesn't have a `ZipCode` property, and you're better off knowing that now then having your code fail at runtime.  My money is on the former though; you probably put in a base type of entity, or the entity for the wrong table.

Comment: @Servy ZipCode exists in the table and it is right type (string). However, maybe parameter scr was not defined before creating "Condition". It was defined in the line : var shippingCalculatorRecords = etc.) If it is so, how can I define it before creating "Condition". Thanks again.

Comment: @user3170203 As I said, it is in the definition of the type of `Condition` that you specify the type of the entity object.  (The type of the property is not important here.)  If you specified the wrong type as the generic argument for `Func` then that would be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but AFAIK I'm afraid you can't do that. However, you can hold on the zip code in a variable and use it later in your condition :

```
string zipcode = string.Empty; //Or an int, if it is stored like so

if (xyz > 0)
    zipcode = "12345";

if (xyz > 1)
    zipcode = "23456";

if (xyz > 2)
    zipcode = "34567";
```

So your condition will now be

```
(scr.CountryId == 0 && src.ZipCode == zipcode)
```

Comment: This assumes the only filters he's adding are for the zip code.

Comment: Representing zipcodes as integers is problematic because leading zeroes are significant.  And if nine-digit zipcodes are used, it becomes worse.

Comment: @SteveWellens Well it depends how it is stored on his side, which I do not know, but the process stays entirely the same, only the declaration/assignment changes a little to accommodate the data type. Reversed the types in my example, but it does not really matter.

Comment: It gets even worse if the ZipCode field is ever used to store international postal codes. We have letters in ours, so we *really* need to use strings, like you have in your edited answer.